# Interacting with sg.image on a clic or a mouse fly over

Tags: image, interaction, pysimplegui

I made a code using pysimplegui. it basically shows some images from a database based on a scanned number. it works but sometimes it could be useful to be able to increase the size of the image + it would make my user interface a bit more interactive

i want to have the possibility to either:

- when i fly over the image with the mouse, i want the image to increase in size
- have the possibility to clic on the image and have a pop-up of the image showing up (in a bigger size)

i am not sure on how to interact with a sg.image()
Below you will find a trunkated part of my code where i show my way of getting the image to show up.

```
layout = [
    [
        sg.Text("Numéro de boîte"),
        sg.Input(size=(25, 1), key="-FILE-"),
        sg.Button("Load Image"),
        sg.Button("Update DATA"),
        sg.Text("<- useless text ")
    ],
    [sg.Text("Indicateur au max" , size = (120, 1),font = ("Arial", 18), justification = "center")],
    [sg.Image(key="-ALV1-"),sg.Image(key="-ALV2-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV3-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV4-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV5-")],
    [sg.Image(key="-ALV6-"),sg.Image(key="-ALV7-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV8-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV9-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV10-")],
    [sg.Text("_" * 350, size = (120, 1), justification = "center")],
    [sg.Text("Indicateur au milieu" , size = (120, 1),font = ("Arial", 18), justification = "center")],
    [sg.Image(key="-ALV11-"),sg.Image(key="-ALV12-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV13-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV14-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV15-")],
    [sg.Image(key="-ALV16-"),sg.Image(key="-ALV17-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV18-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV19-"), sg.Image(key="-ALV20-")],
    [sg.Text("↓↓↓  ↓↓↓" , size = (120, 1),font = ("Arial", 18), justification = "center")],
    
]

ImageAlv1 = Image.open(PathAlv1)
ImageAlv1.thumbnail((250, 250))
bio1 = io.BytesIO()
ImageAlv1.save(bio1, format="PNG")
window["-ALV1-"].update(data=bio1.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `bind` method for events, like

- `"<Enter>"`, the user moved the mouse pointer into a visible part of an element.
- `"<Double-1>"`, specifies two click events happening close together in time.

Using `PIL.Image` to resize image and `io.BytesIO` as buffer.

```py
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def resize(image, size=(256, 256)):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(image)
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(imgdata))
    width, height = size
    w, h = im.size
    scale = min(width/w, height/h)
    new_size = (int(w*scale+0.5), int(h*scale+0.5))
    new_im = im.resize(new_size, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    buffer = BytesIO()
    new_im.save(buffer, format="PNG")
    return buffer.getvalue()

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

number = 4
column_layout, line = [], []
limit = len(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST) - 1
for i, image in enumerate(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST):
    line.append(sg.Image(data=image, size=(64, 64), pad=(1, 1), background_color='#10C000', expand_y=True, key=f'IMAGE {i}'))
    if i % number == number-1 or i == limit:
        column_layout.append(line)
        line = []
layout = [
    [sg.Image(size=(256, 256), pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True, background_color='green', key='-IMAGE-'),
     sg.Column(column_layout, expand_y=True, pad=(0, 0))],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
for i in range(limit+1):
    window[f'IMAGE {i}'].bind("<Enter>", "")        # Binding for Mouse enter sg.Image
    #window[f'IMAGE {i}'].bind("<Double-1>", "")    # Binding for Mouse double click on sg.Image
element = window['-IMAGE-']
now = None
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event.startswith("IMAGE"):
        index = int(event.split()[-1])
        if index != now:
            element.update(data=resize(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[index]))
            now = index

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try this ASAP. I'll keep you updated